# JSP code not working

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<h1>hello saurabh</h1>
<%

String s1  = request.getParameter("uname");
String s2="saurabh";

String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/amber";

String userName = "root";

String password = "sameer0207";

Connection conn = null;

Statement st = null;
out.println(s2);

try {
    out.println("Enterd in try");

    Class.forName(driver);
        out.println(driver);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
        out.println("Connected to the database");

    String query="INSERT INTO quote VALUES (garima, 8588803860, 'tyagi619@gmail.com', 'kuchb bhi');";
    st = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs.next())
    {out.println("success");
     conn.close();}
    else
    {out.println("not success");}

      }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception occured! "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
                }  


%>
```

Absolutely new to programming wanted to insert values into the database(mysql) but don't know what wrong I am doing.
logging in mysql via root password sameer0207 then using a database named amber, using tomcat server i am deploying the web app while running on tomcat I can see that after the class.ForName nothing gets executed don't know why?
please help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you added MySQL dependencies in your class path? and please paste what console error  you are getting

Comment: Thanks all for the reply...My error has been solved..

Comment: Saurabh, please add the solution which worked for you as answer to your own question. Accept it. So that, other users of stackoverflow community can take help from it in future, if they stuck on same path...!! I hope you also believe that it's a nicer practice to share knowledge, right ?? :)